# URL Routing Not Working in ASP .Net MVC2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I am working ASP.Net MVC2 application.
In that i have used URL Routing

To get URL as

```
    https://localhost/StudentDetail/SortField
```

I have written below code in Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
"StudentDetail", // Route name
"StudentDetail/{SortField}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "UDashboard", action = "UAboutMeStudentDetails", 
     SortField = "Major" }
);
```

And In my view link is as below

```
<a href="/StudentDetail?SortField='Major'" >Students</a>
```

But it is not working. and my URL is

```
https://localhost/StudentDetail?SortField='Major'
```

Can anyone please help me to get the required URL..?

I want URL as

```
https://localhost/StudentDetail/SortField
```

Thanks In Advance, Prashant

Comment: `<a href="/StudentDetail/Major" >Students</a>` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an incorrect thought on how routing works.  Your route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"StudentDetail", // Route name
"StudentDetail/{SortField}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "UDashboard", action = "UAboutMeStudentDetails", 
     SortField = "Major" }
);
```

Will take the SortFeild parameter (Major, Gpa, etc), and replace {SortField} with that value.  So, using the following actionlink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Student Details", "UAboutMeStudentDetails", new {controller="UDashboard", SortField = "Major})
```

would produce the following HTML

```
<a href="/StudentDetail/Major">Student Details</a>
```

Note that the value of SortField has replaced the {SortField} parameter in your route.  You would never get a URL looking like what you are requesting as how would you get the value of SortField to the action?